# Justifying the result of $\lim_{x \mapsto \infty }\left ( x-\sqrt{x²-2x} \right )$

Tags: limits

I am working with the next limit:

$$\lim_{x \mapsto \infty  }\left ( x-\sqrt{x²-2x} \right )$$

I intuitively know that since $x^2$ increases faster than $x$, when x tends to infinte this limit for a sufficient big $x$ its approximately:
$$\lim_{x \mapsto \infty  }\left ( x-\sqrt{x²-2x} \right )\approx \lim_{x \mapsto \infty  }\left ( x-\sqrt{x²} \right )\approx0$$

when $x$ tends to infinite,
Due to that fact, I think that the result of the limit it's:

$$\lim_{x \mapsto \infty  }\left ( x-\sqrt{x²-2x} \right )=0$$

However, I need a some more mathematical justification rather than the intuitive justification, I would appreciate any help or hint to justify this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Write, as $x \to +\infty$,
$$
 x-\sqrt{x^2-2x}=\frac{( x-\sqrt{x^2-2x})( x+\sqrt{x^2-2x})}{ x+\sqrt{x^2-2x}}=\frac{2x}{ x+\sqrt{x^2-2x}}\to 1
$$

Comment: $=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}}$, if $x>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the support that really helped me, I didn't try with multiplying by a 1.

Answer (score 2):

Olivier has a fine answer with the right result.

Here is what is wrong with your intuition.

Letting $y=x-1$ then:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x-\sqrt{x^2-2x}\right) = 1+\lim_{y\to\infty} \left(y-\sqrt{y^2-1}\right)$$

Your intuition would give that both of these limits are zero, which would give:

$$0=1+0.$$

Answer (score 0):

A result
that makes this easy
is that
$\sqrt{1+z}
\approx 1+z/2
$
for small $z$.

More generally,
$(1+z)^a
\approx 1+az
$
for small $z$
and real $a$.

And,
of course,
by Taylor,
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x) + hf'(x)
$
for small $h$.
From this,
let
$f(x) = (1+x)^a$.

Answer (score 0):

We transform the indeterminate form as follows$$x-\sqrt{x^2-2x}=x(1-\sqrt{1-2/x})=\frac {1-\sqrt{1-2/x}}{\frac1x}$$
Hence applying l'Hôpital Rule one time we get   $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2/x}}$$ for the limit when $x\mapsto \infty$. It is clear now that the searched limit is equal to $1$